# How do I read env-vars from Azure container app

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-apps

How can I get the --env-vars in my app inside the container app?

```
az containerapp create \
  --resource-group "my-resource-group" \
  --name myQueueApp \
  --environment "my-environment-name" \
  --image demos/myQueueApp:v1 \
  --secrets "queue-connection-string=$CONNECTIONSTRING" \
  --env-vars "QueueName=myqueue" "ConnectionString=secretref:queue-connection-string"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--env-vars` is setting environment variables on your container. You get them the same way you would normally get environment variables in a process.

See also: [Where are environment variables located in a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71234647/where-are-environment-variables-located-in-a-docker-container)